Issue rendering specific web page on native android activity
I'm having an issue with the render of a web page in my native android activity. The problem isn't with all web pages. Pages such as Facebook, Amazon, YouTube and so forth, are rendered perfectly fine in my activity, but with the page that I'm pretending to render, I only got a "blank screen". I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with the webpage.
At the begging I thought that it was a certificate issue, but apparently it has the proper security certificate:
certificate
The code of my Activity is the following:
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebResourceError;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class OutgoingCallActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_outgoing_call);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
                Log.e("WEBVIEW_ERROR", error.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                Log.d("WEBVIEW", "onPageFinished: " + url);
                view.evaluateJavascript(
            "(function() { return document.body.innerHTML; })();",
                        new ValueCallback<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onReceiveValue(String html) {
                                Log.d("HTML", html);
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.amazon.com/");
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String number = "123456";
                Uri call = Uri.parse("tel:" + number);
                    Intent surf = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, call);
                startActivity(surf);
                Log.d("OutgoingCallActivity", "Button Pressed");
            }
        });
    }
}

class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void sendMessageToApp(String deeplink) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(deeplink));
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }
}

The activity consists of a WebView and a native button:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".OutgoingCallActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="700dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#5bc500"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:text="Resume Call" />
</LinearLayout>

I'm not sure if I have to include some extra configuration in my native code or web code.
As you can see I'm logging if occur any errors at the moment of loading the page, but I have no errors.
NOTE 1: The page was developed with NEXTJS.
NOTE 2: The WebAppInterface is only to send deeplinks to the app when the user press some buttons in the web side.
NOTE 3: This behavior happens in all android versions from 7.1.1 until 13.
NOTE 4: I'm working for a private company, so I can't share the web url here, at least, not in this public post.
I tried to render my web page and the result is:
blank screen
I tried both, render the web page in android emulator and physical android device, and the result is the same, my web page doesn't render.
But as I said above, when I use pages such as Facebook, Amazon, Disney and so on, the pages are rendered perfectly fine:
expected behavior
I'm not sure whats wrong with the page I'm trying to render. Hope you can help me.
